# Java String split by whitespace not working

Tags: java, regex, arraylist, hashmap, split

I am trying to pass an input string into an ArrayList of HashMap, and have written a method for it.

```
public static ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> tagSeparator (String input) {
    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> listOfTags = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
    HashMap<String, String> newTags = new HashMap<String, String>();        
    for (String eachLine: input.split("/>")) {
        eachLine = (eachLine.trim()).substring(eachLine.indexOf("<")+1);
        newTags.put("TagName", eachLine.substring(0, eachLine.indexOf(" ")));
        eachLine = eachLine.substring(eachLine.indexOf(" "));
        for (String AttrVal: eachLine.split(CharMatcher.WHITESPACE.toString())) {
            System.out.println("AttrVal: " + AttrVal);
            String Attr = AttrVal.substring(0, AttrVal.indexOf("="));
            String Val = CharMatcher.is('"').trimFrom(AttrVal.substring(AttrVal.indexOf("=")));
            newTags.put(Attr, Val);             
        }           
        listOfTags.add(newTags);
        newTags.clear();
      }     
    return listOfTags;      
}
```

I am giving the input as given below -

`<AssinaturaTax12110000 Tag="12110000" TaxName="ICMS" TaxRate="25.00" TaxAmount="24.75"/>
<AssinaturaTax12110000 Tag="12110000" TaxName="PIS" TaxRate="0.65" TaxAmount="0.64"/>
<AssinaturaTax12110000 Tag="12110000" TaxName="COFINS" TaxRate="3.00" TaxAmount="2.97"/>`

The first for-each loop is supposed to separate the lines, and the second for-each loop is supposed to separate the AVP in each line. I have used [Guava](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/) to identify Whitespace in the second for-each loop. While the first for-each loop works as expected, in case of the second one, the String split is not working. I have tried using the regex " ", "\\s+" and "\\s", as well as the Apache Commons StringUtils split method, but failed to produce the desired output.

There is a StringIndexOutOfBounds exception and the console output comes as given below -

```
AttrVal: Tag="12110000" TaxName="ICMS" TaxRate="25.00" TaxAmount="24.75"
```

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: There is a lot of `indexOf(String)` method that is called... yo should check that the result is not -1..... it some place something like that is occurring, try to debug it carefully.

Comment: just use jaxb marshaller!

Comment: Biffen and Wheee are correct, but could you please actually post the full stack trace, or at a minimum the error message?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a few problems with your code:

1. You really should use an XML parser like Biffen suggested. It makes life a lot easier and prevents mistakes.
2. The second for-each statement splits on whitespace characters. However the string itself starts with a whitespace character (on my computer: [ Tag="12110000" TaxName="ICMS" TaxRate="25.00" TaxAmount="24.75"]). After splitting on whitespace, the first piece is an empty String from which you try to take a substring which is obviously not possible. To solve this simply use: `for (String AttrVal: eachLine.trim().split("[\\s]+"))` instead of `for (String AttrVal: eachLine.split("[\\s]+"))`. The trim() function automatically deletes whitespace characters at the start and end of a String.
3. You add your HashMap to an ArrayList and then clear the HashMap. Since the ArrayList keeps a reference to the map, you will end up with an ArrayList of empty HashMaps. Either construct a new HashMap for each line in the input or create a copy of the HashMap you have by using the following constructor: `HashMap<String,String> copy = new HashMap(newTags);`. Then add the copy to the ArrayList. By using that constructor all values in newTags are copied and no reference is kept to newTags, so you can do whatever you want with newTags, such as clearing it.